# VBA adding a list empty fields from a userform to a message box

Tags: vba, ms-word, msgbox

I have created a userform that requires the user to input several strings or integers. I am trying to get a message box come up if several of the mandatory boxes are not filled in. I want to list the empty fields but skip the fields that are filled in. I know how to do a for loop if the values were integers but most of the inputs are strings.  I think I could do something with Dim C as control, and I know the general layout of my message box, but I am stumped beyond that. Please help so that I don’t have to write six separate conditional statements with six separate message boxes!

The six form field names are:
Proposal_Name, Date_of_Submission, cboContraact_type, Contract_Neg_Name, Contract_Neg_Number, and Validity_Period

The general layout of the message box I had in mind is as follows:

```
MsgBox "You have left the following mandatory fields empty:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Proposal_Name" & vbNewLine & "Date_of_Submission" & Chr(10) & "cboContraact_type" & Chr(10) & "Contract_Neg_Name" & Chr(10) & "Validity_Period"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only concerned about 6 fields, I would not go down the path of looping through the form controls, determining the control type, checking for missing value, etc.

Here is an OnClick for a Command Button that might work for you:

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()


Dim sMissingValues As String
sMissingValues = ""

If Nz(Me!Proposal_Name, "") = "" Then sMissingValues = sMissingValues + vbCrLf + "Proposal_Name"
If Nz(Me!Date_of_Submission, "") = "" Then sMissingValues = sMissingValues + vbCrLf + "Date_of_Submission"
If Nz(Me!cboContraact_type, "") = "" Then sMissingValues = sMissingValues + vbCrLf + "cboContraact_type"
If Nz(Me!Contract_Neg_Name, "") = "" Then sMissingValues = sMissingValues + vbCrLf + "Contract_Neg_Name"
If Nz(Me!Contract_Neg_Number, "") = "" Then sMissingValues = sMissingValues + vbCrLf     + "Contract_Neg_Number"
If Nz(Me!Validity_Period, "") = "" Then sMissingValues = sMissingValues + vbCrLf + "Validity_Period"

If sMissingValues <> "" Then
    MsgBox "You have left the following mandatory fields empty:" & vbCrLf & sMissingValues
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I altered it a bit to If Len(Me.Proposal_Name & vbNullString) = 0 Then.... it works great. Thanks again.